# How to skip a line in my VBA if the cell is equal to "" (as in a fake blank)

Tags: vba, excel

Good day to you all.

I wonder what I should add in these codes to get it working. This is just a simple code to copy and paste a sheet onto Outlook and attach few files. I am not copying everything here because I have found out that the problem exactly lies in the below codes.

```
   StrAtt1 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PDF\" & Worksheets("PDF_Generator").Range("B36")
   StrAtt2 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PDF\" & Worksheets("PDF_Generator").Range("B39")
   StrAtt3 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PDF\" & Worksheets("PDF_Generator").Range("B40")
   .To = Worksheets("PDF_Generator").Range("B8")
   .CC = "Myself"
   .BCC = ""
   .Subject = Worksheets("PDF_Generator").Range("B38")
   .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
   .attachments.Add StrAtt1
   .attachments.Add StrAtt2
   .attachments.Add StrAtt3
```

The problem comes when B39 or B40 is empty, which B39 and B40 itself is a formula depending on conditions and might return to "" (a fake blank)
I have tried to debug it by deleting StrAtt2 and StrAtt3 lines and it works perfectly fine, because B36 will always return a non empty cell and finds the right attachment.

I wonder if I could add few lines to let the VBA understand that I want to **skip** StrAtt2 and StrAtt3 **if the cell is "" or blank**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can just place the statements that you don't want to execute inside an `If` statement:

```
If Worksheets("PDF_Generator").Range("B39").Value <> "" Then
    .attachments.Add StrAtt2
End If
If Worksheets("PDF_Generator").Range("B40").Value <> "" Then
    .attachments.Add StrAtt3
End If
```

Comment: Thanks I picked this solution

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if the string ends with `\`:

```
StrAtt2 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PDF\" & Worksheets("PDF_Generator").Range("B39")

If Right(StrAtt2) <> "\" Then .attachments.Add StrAtt2
```

or loop the cells:

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PDF_Generator").Range("B36,B39,B40")
    If cell.Value2 > "" Then .attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PDF\" & cell.Value2
Next
```

Comment: No, they end with "" for definite, but thanks for your try, I got my fix!

Comment: @keiar that was meant for after they are set to `StrAtt2 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PDF\" & Worksheets("PDF_Generator").Range("B39")` so they don't end with `""`, but you can accept the other answer if it answered your question by clicking on the check mark next to it http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
Dim StrArr
Dim lngRow As Long

With Worksheets("PDF_Generator")
    StrArr = Array(.Range("B36"), .Range("B39"), .Range("B40"))
    For lngRow = 0 To UBound(StrArr)
        If Len(StrArr(lngRow)) Then .attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PDF\" & StrArr(lngRow)
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks more complex and should serve the purpose too, I took the simple one instead

Comment: Fair enough :) Arrays (as I used) are faster than loops and if your code was to grow, handling each test specifically wouldnt work.